# Bind: Zone not loaded due to errors, all FQDNs properly marked

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

After an update, our intranet manual stopped working, and we get an error about our zone file when we run named-checkzone that says "intranet.dsi.local has no address records (A or AAAA)" and is not loaded due to errors

```
$ttl 38400
@   IN  SOA intranet.dsi.local. root.intranet.dsi.local. (
            1542053403
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )
dsi.local.  IN  NS  intranet.dsi.local.
dsi.local.  IN  A   199.168.52.xx
www.dsi.local.  IN  A   199.168.52.xx
ftp.dsi.local.  IN  A   199.168.52.xx
m.dsi.local.    IN  A   199.168.52.xx
localhost.dsi.local.    IN  A   127.0.0.1
webmail.dsi.local.  IN  A   199.168.52.xx
admin.dsi.local.    IN  A   199.168.52.xx
dsi.local.  IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx a:dsi.local ip4:192.168.10.195 ip4:199.168.52.xx ip6:fe80::20c:29ff:fe3e:690b ?all"
```

Nothing's actually changed in the file, and as far as I can tell, all FQDNs have . at the end, so I'm not sure what's gone wrong. I wasn't the one who originally set this up, but my predecessor has since left the company, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: There is `intranet.dsi.local.`  resource record in the zone data that you've posted. You reference that in your SOA and NS records, which is why bind refuses to load the zone.

Comment: so if I replace intranet.dsi.local. in the NS record with, say, the ip address that it's supposed to map to, in this case 192.168.10.195, it should work again?

Comment: I was actually able to get it to play nice syntax-wise by adding `intranet.dsi.local.  IN  A  192.168.10.195`, however the site still refuses to load with anything other than a direct IP address, and even then loads without the dynamically linked scripts and themes

Comment: Figured out that in addition to this little error, my replacement added a new domain controller right before he left and never updated the DNS settings in it to allow the intranet manual to work properly